# Transform string into array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm sure this has been answered, but I have no idea how to research it. This is my string

```
[value1, value2, value3, ..., valueN]
```

and I'd like to know if there's a native function that transform it into a simple array

```
array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', ..., 'valueN');
```

Let it be clear that I'm looking to know if there's something already written that do it, that is, another approach other than `strpos('[')` and `implode(',')`.

---

### Edit

Sorry I haven't given much attention to this question because I'm working non-stop on this project that required me to ask this question. Regarding the last comment, I'd like to add here that that is no an issue, but how it was planned. I decided to make the arrays look exactly like JSON arrays because I wanted an easy function to undo it. Here is my INI file.

```
; Default Pages
user = all
wordpress = all    
home/welcome = visitor
home/customer = visitor
home/new = visitor
home/signup = visitor

; User
user/panel = '["user", "worker", "customer", "company", "staff", "ruler", "gifter", "support", "salesman", "scorer", "recorder", "reporter", "deliverer", "manager", "admin"]'
user/profile = user
user/password = user
user/support = user

; Reporter
user/report = reporter

; User/Customer
user/customer/voucher = customer
user/customer/history = customer
user/customer/ticket = customer
user/customer/profiling = customer

; User/Staff
user/staff/customer = recorder

; User/Manager
user/staff/score = scorer
user/staff/voucher = deliverer

user/manager/shop = '["salesman", "manager"]'

user/manager/staff = manager
user/manager/ticket = manager
```

Comment: Regex is a Wizard's feature that I've probably spent more than 100 hours trying to master it and can't :( though I think it would be a good option considering that it could be done in one line of code.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does what you want. Just use `explode()` after removing the brackes.

Comment: `json_decode()` can decode that to an array.

Comment: @Phylogenesis exactly my point. If json_decode can transform an array into that string, why json_encode is not working reversely?

Comment: here is the regex https://regex101.com/r/bF4gZ2/5.

Comment: `strpos('[')` and `explode(',')` are probably your best bet. Don't use regex. That'd be a really poor choice for this.

Comment: That array looks suspiciously similar to a json array...

Comment: Not so sure now. The values are unquoted. If you're expecting the values to be strings, then `json_decode()` will fail.

Comment: @STTLCU exactly my point. If json_encode can transform an array into that, why can't json_decode reverse it?

Comment: so if I use "quotation" between each value, json_decode should work?

Comment: Yes, if the string is `[ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' ... ]` then `json_decode` will work.

Comment: Can we go a little bit more upstream? who generated that "array"? how? because imho it's easier to properly json_encode it and decode later than build workarounds.

Comment: @STTLCU That value comes from an .ini file through `parse_ini_file` function. It should have been "quoted", but PHP is removing the quotes on the `parse_ini_file` function. All I have to do is use single-quotes around the values inside the .ini file and voilà.

Comment: @AvinashRaj How did you even found this question? It doesn't have any regex tag? Did you got lost? (Here is the way [home](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex))

Comment: @Rizier123 my favorite tags, `regex`,`awk`, `sed`, `bash`, `string` sometimes `python.` because we could solve 40-50% of questions tagged as string would be solved easily through regex :-) time to sleep. bye...

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu if that's the case, there must be something you're making to extract that string from the ini file, because that's not how parse_ini_file works. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

You said in comments that the string comes from a `parse_ini_file` function call.

The first string is NOT what it's returned by a parse_ini_file call, so there must be something else you're doing to get that input, and that isn't necessary at all.

To obtain what you asked in your question, you should do something like this:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file($ini_path); //This is an associative array
//If necessary, get only the key=>value pairs you need
//otherwise, just keep going
$ini_values = array_values($ini_array); //this is now a 0-based array
```

`$ini_values` now contains exactly what you asked.

Comment: Although I appreciate the effort in helping me, that was not exactly what I meant. I used to have only strings on my .ini file, but now I'm implementing a new role system which requires a more careful planning and the fact that I'm getting that result from the ini is not a problem, but a planning. See my EDIT for clarification.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu you should use ini file sections to have another level in your resulting array rather than messy json-styled strings. I do think you're going to regret your current approach down the line. It's time for a proper database.

Comment: I don't want to go for a database because it's a rather limited number of "rows". The number of pages in a system is predefined. If a developer doesn't create the page, it doesn't exist. Before this, I was using bit-wise comparison to allow/deny access, so each row would hold a `2^n` number and in order to verify which is the "homepage", I'd move exponentially from 2^1. Now I'm implementing roles and I need another way to define which is the homepage for each "role" and the architecture allows me to choose which system to use at a project, so the existence of the new doesn't exclude the old.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Please, a database is still easier, cleaner and generally better to use. If you're worried about size, consider something like SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

implode() for simple things or preg_split() for regex.

http://php.net/function.implode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

I used to be weary of learning regex, but this site is imensely helpful, it visually shows what your string will do, and has cheatsheet and examples.

https://www.debuggex.com/